# How to block or forward packets with custom and dynamic rules

Tags: firewall, access-control-list

I would like to block or forward TCP requests from clients to WAN according to source and destination ip addresses. The problem is that this ip couples are stored in a mysql database and they can change quite often, how can I do this?

I tried pfsense but I can not add custom rule. What I'm looking for is something like custom ACL in squid, but for all connections and not only HTTP.
Is it possibile?

Answer (score 0):

I know a snort(https://www.snort.org/) box can be set up to accomplish this when its configured to act like an IPS. It will allow you to create very granular rules including protocol types and IP ranges. I have done it once in a lab environment, it wasn't the simplest thing to set up and it may be overkill for your requirements. But its free and it will accomplish you task.

Here is a tutorial:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/58e72888-6340-46ac-b488-d31aa4058e9c/entry/august_8_2012_12_01_pm6?lang=en